# Keep leading zeros in specific column when running batch file that splits csv files into multiple files

Tags: excel, csv, batch-file

I have a csv file which is over the number of rows allowed in Excel. I'm running a batch file (listed) below to split into multiple CSV files. The code works and splits into multiple files. However, there are two fields (2 and 3rd) in the file that have leading zeros that I would like to keep.

Is there a way I can set those two specific fields to be imported as text to keep the leading zeros?

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET BFN=Test.csv
SET LPF=1048576
SET SFN=Test_Split

REM Do not change beyond this line.
SET SFX=%BFN:~-3%
SET /A LineNum=0
SET /A FileNum=1
For /F "delims=" %%l in (%BFN%) Do (
    SET /A LineNum+=1
    echo %%l >> %SFN%!FileNum!.%SFX%
    if !LineNum! EQU !LPF! (
        SET /A LineNum=0
        SET /A FileNum+=1
    )
)
endlocal
Pause
```

Comment: Sounds like an excel problem.  Not a batch-file problem.

Comment: In Excel's wizard for importing text files, you can specify that the 2nd and 3rd fields are Text (instead of General). Specifying text will retain leading zeros.